# Получение разных результатов при одинаковых тестах IntelljIdea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gui

Начал разрабатывать оконное приложение на Java при помощи среды IntelljIdea. Добавил кнопки Open и Save в меню. Пока что приложение выглядит следующим образом
[image: В меню file выпадающий список и там есть пункты Open и Save]

Добавил обработку нажатий на open и save(они находятся в File->Open/Save)
Описал это следующим образом

```
JFrame mainActivity;
    JFileChooser filter;
    JFileChooser saver;

    testApp() {
        // создание главной активности
        mainActivity = new JFrame();
        mainActivity.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainActivity.setSize(500,500);

        selectedFile = new JLabel();

        mainText = new JTextArea();

        JMenuBar topMenu = new JMenuBar();
        // создание заголовков меню
        JMenu files = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu project = new JMenu("Project");
        JMenu design = new JMenu("Design");
        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
        // добавление заголовков в меню
        topMenu.add(files);
        topMenu.add(edit);
        topMenu.add(project);
        topMenu.add(design);
        topMenu.add(help);
        // создание подпунктов меню files
        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open", KeyEvent.VK_O);
        JMenuItem newFile = new JMenuItem("New", KeyEvent.VK_N);
        JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save", KeyEvent.VK_S);
        JMenuItem saveAs = new JMenuItem("Save as...");
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        //разделитель
        JSeparator separatorFiles = new JSeparator();
        // добавление хоткеев
        open.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        newFile.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        save.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        // добавление подпунктов в меню файлов files
        files.add(open);
        files.add(newFile);
        files.add(save);
        files.add(saveAs);
        files.add(separatorFiles);
        files.add(exit);

        files.addActionListener(this);
        open.addActionListener(this);
        save.addActionListener(this);

        mainActivity.getContentPane().add(mainText);
        mainActivity.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, topMenu);
        mainActivity.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Также описал действия, при выборе пункта меню

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        String commandString = event.getActionCommand();

        if (commandString.equals("Exit")){
            int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainActivity, "Сохранить файл?");
            switch(response){
                case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION: {
                    break;
                }
                case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION: {
                    break;
                }
                case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION: {
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (commandString.equals("Open")){
            if(!dir.equals(""))
                filter = new JFileChooser(dir);
            else
                filter = new JFileChooser();
            filter.setFileFilter(new AsmFileFilter());
            int result = filter.showOpenDialog(mainActivity);
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                workFile = new File(filter.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                dir = filter.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                System.out.println("Беру файл \"" + workFile + "\"");
                try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(workFile.toString()), "cp1251")))
                {
                    String s;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
                        sb.append(s).append(System.lineSeparator());
                    }
                    mainText.setText(sb.toString());
                    scroll = new JScrollPane(mainText);
                    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                    mainActivity.getContentPane().add(scroll);
                }
                catch(IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            else {
                selectedFile.setText("No file selected!");
            }
        }
        if (commandString.equals("Save")) {
            if (!dir.equals(""))
                saver = new JFileChooser(dir);
            else
                saver = new JFileChooser();
            int result = saver.showSaveDialog(mainActivity);
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                saveFile = new File(saver.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                dir = saver.getSelectedFile().getPath();

                try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(saveFile, false))
                {
                    int j = 0;
                    int k = mainText.getLineCount();
                    ArrayList<String> allString = new ArrayList<>();
                    String allText = mainText.getText();
                    for (String buffer : allText.split("\n")){
                        allString.add(buffer);
                    }
                    while (j < allString.size()){

                        writer.write(allString.get(j) + "\n");
                        j++;
                    }
                    writer.flush();
                }
                catch(IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }
   }
```

При нажатии на кнопку Open вызывается диалоговое окно с выбором файла[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Далее выбирается файл, считывается построчно и выводится в текстовое поле mainText
Все поля, используемые в приложении описаны следующим образом, инициализация происходит в момент нажатия на кнопку контекстного меню.
        JTextArea mainText;

```
    JLabel selectedFile;
    JScrollPane scroll;
    // работа с файлами
    File workFile;
    File saveFile;
    JFrame mainActivity;
    JFileChooser filter;
    JFileChooser saver;
```

При первом открытии файла всё работает корректно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Однако далее, если попробовать открыть другой файл, то текст в mainText не изменится (если это тестировать через обычный запуск т.е. Run). А в случае отладки, текст после повторного выбора файла изменится в mainText. Не могу понять в чём проблема? Если необходимо, то могу попробовать записать видео с отладкой, чтобы более подробно и понятно раскрыть проблему, возникшую у меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена
код, в котором была ошибка

```
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                workFile = new File(filter.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                dir = filter.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                System.out.println("Беру файл \"" + workFile + "\"");
                try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(workFile.toString()), "cp1251")))
                {
                    String s;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
                        sb.append(s).append(System.lineSeparator());
                    }
                    mainText.setText(sb.toString());
                    scroll = new JScrollPane(mainText);
                    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                    mainActivity.getContentPane().add(scroll);
                }
                catch(IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

При каждом новом запуске файла у меня создавалась новая панель прокручивания

```
scroll = new JScrollPane(mainText);
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
mainActivity.getContentPane().add(scroll);
```

, в которую я добавлял новый текст. В режиме debug фокус передавался иначе, чем при запуске приложения при помощи кнопки Run. Это можно исправить просто добавив условие. Создавалось ли окно с прокручиванием, если да, то просто добавить в него текст, иначе - создать окно с прокручиванием

```
if (commandString.equals("Open")){
            if(!dir.equals(""))
                filter = new JFileChooser(dir);
            else
                filter = new JFileChooser();
            filter.setFileFilter(new AsmFileFilter());
            int result = filter.showOpenDialog(mainActivity);
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                workFile = new File(filter.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                dir = filter.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                System.out.println("Беру файл \"" + workFile + "\"");
                try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(workFile.toString()), "cp1251")))
                {
                    String s;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
                        sb.append(s).append(System.lineSeparator());
                    }
                    mainText.setText(sb.toString());

                    if(!isCreate){
                        scroll = new JScrollPane(mainText);
                        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                        mainActivity.getContentPane().add(scroll);
                        isCreate = true;
                    }

                }
                catch(IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

Comment: почему просто не создать и не добавить скрол вместе с `mainText` в `testApp()`?